# Do NOT connect this water heater to a CFCI or AFIC Circuit. Why?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a 190K BTU Natural Gas Rheem tankless on demand water heater in a barn. It also requires a 120v electrical connection. The instructions say, "Do NOT connect this water heater to a CFCI or AFCI Circuit." However, the power to the barn is supplied by a 20Amp Underground Feeder that is on a GFCI+AFCI breaker.

Why would instructions say this and what can I expect if I connect the water heater to this circuit? The instructions say that "the water heater only draws a maximum of 3 amps of current" that are mostly used to run the on board electronics.

Water Heater: https://www.homedepot.com/p/Rheem-Performance-Platinum-9-5-GPM-Natural-Gas-High-Efficiency-Indoor-Tankless-Water-Heater-ECOH200DVLN-2/304820618
Rheem ECOH200DVLN

Comment: A quick search turned up numerous referenced to mostly Rheem tankless water heaters "nuisance" tripping AFCI and/or GFCI breakers.  This is why Rheem says not to use one.  If you have no choice on the breaker, get a different water heater that doesn't have this restriction.  I'm going to guess that it's a characteristic of their circuit design that fools the breaker into thinking there is an AF or GF.

Comment: Can you get us a model number please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I updated the post with Water Heater model and link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### It's the ignition system

Your tankless water heater, like many gas-fired appliances, uses an electronic Direct Spark Ignition (DSI) system to light the burner instead of a standing pilot light.  This saves gas, but requires the electronics to generate a high voltage in order to get sufficient spark energy to ignite the gas reliably.  In order to keep the implementation from becoming too bulky or complicated, the high voltage is generated relative to the chassis of the appliance using an HV supply that is not isolated from mains earth, so that the spark igniter's counter electrode can be a grounded burner part instead of having to be insulated for the full ignition voltage.  This, in turn, trips up GFCIs and many AFCIs, since it effectively acts as an intermittent leakage path to ground.